# ScoreloopUI -> Source is not found

Tags: android, eclipse, scoreloop

I want to add Scoreloop in my App. I tried it with the official tutorial, but after I wrote my game secret (like the special ID for this site) in the code, eclipse has this problem: "Source not found"

This is my Application Code:

**Edit:**

Good.

I changed the code. Scoreloop is saying (The tutorial): This code should work. The file exist. But it's still not working.

```
package com.example.littlepigs;

import android.app.Application;

import com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ScoreloopManagerSingleton;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ScoreloopManagerSingleton.init(this,
                "SAGk1GZeD3hqJOoThZTWM3YlCFuvgAdZrGgjU6TSCecUw1FnNCJDhw==");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        ScoreloopManagerSingleton.destroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: com.scoreloop.client.android.core.model.Client;

So this line refers to a file called Client in your com.scoreloop.client package under /android/core/model/Client.java,

Does this file exist?

Comment: I don't know. I do not find this folder. But it was the autocorrect of eclipse, so I guess?

Comment: Eclipse isn't always correct, it's a best guess at most, It seems you're following the SDK Tutorial, I would probably find a decent Youtube Video tutorial instead, as the SDK Examples tend to be aimed at developers who know what they're doing and just want to see what they need. Try searching youtube for "android game tutorial for beginners" I know it will be frustrating starting again but having an idea of how packages work will save you from further headaches.

Comment: Ok. I used the Explorer now to find the Client.java. It's not there and I am pretty sure, that the folder is not exist as well.

Comment: But, how you can see. It wasn't the (only) problem. The weird thing is, that no one else have this problem.

Comment: @Pheonix2105: What do you think now?

Comment: When you open the ScoreloopManagerSingleton class are all the imports at the top where they are supposed to be and what error are you getting now? Can you link me the tutorial too and I'll have a look see if I can spot anything.

Comment: How I sad, I did not wrote it, but a lot of people are using this, so I am pretty sure. I get the same error: Source not found.
This is difficult, cause I do not know where this is online.

Comment: When you download the SDK it is inside I hope this is all: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lkt11r1c5k1hb1j/scoreloopui-basicintegration.html
https://www.dropbox.com/s/00t6zp7fn0ekdm2/scoreloopui-integrateconfigure.html
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uo41xe7gt1txf72/scoreloopui-initialisation.html
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf6inv4ig9mb2fz/scoreloopui-androidmanifest.html
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvxvy0w1nyn70ar/projectsetup.html

Comment: Ah I see, I Thought it was online, I'll take a look at the copy I have.

Comment: Thank you! This are 5 files, but I do not think, that you will find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214659/implementing-scoreloop-on-android?rq=1 Which you should take a look at as it's very similar to yours.

First let's fix the class, you should extend Application not Android.app.Application.

Fix this and copy me the error you get in LogCat have you already create a class called Application that you are extending or is it a base android class?

```
package com.example.littlepigs;

import com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ScoreloopManagerSingleton;

public class Application extends Application //not android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            ScoreloopManagerSingleton.init(this, "secret");
    }

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        ScoreloopManagerSingleton.destroy();
}

}
```

You also don't need to import context, context is saying "what am I doing this as?" So when you pass

`ScoreloopManagerSingleton.init(this, "secret");`

You are really saying "Start a new ScoreLoopManagerSingleton as Application1"

context is saying "who am I doing this as?"

ScoreloopManagerSingleton.init(this(which would mean Application1's context), "secret")

Comment: You have to take the look on the new code, should I delete the old one?

Comment: Start a new question since you are not having the Source Code not found problem now and link it here so I can find it :)

Comment: Sorry I was confused, is your problem still 
"ScoreloopUI -> Source is not found"? 

If it is not and that problem is gone, you should mention what you did to fix it so when other people search "ScoreloopUI -> Source is not found" they can find the answer to this problem too. 

If you have another problem now that isn't "ScoreloopUI -> Source is not found" then start a new question about it and link it to me and we can try solve it :).

Comment: But I have the same problem: "Source not found"

Comment: Right, ok sorry I thought you solved that because you have the singleton manager code above. What is the error you get in LogCat? (all of it) update your question with it, helps us see better exactly what's not working right.

Comment: Sorry. What do you meen with LogCat?

Comment: It's the program that logs all the runtime errors in eclipse, have a look at this you will probably know what I mean once you see it http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html#logcatview  - You should check the rest of the site out too, Vogella Tutorials are very thorough.

Comment: Oh, yes. What do you want to have?

Comment: Change it from "Verbose" to "Error" and copy all of what's there into your question in a code box :)

Comment: You also don't need  import android.app.Application; anymore.

Comment: I have to import. Because of this: "Application cannot be resolved to a type" - It's not working when I delete the import.

Comment: Is there anything in the Console View? Where are you seeing this Source not found error in Eclipse when you hover over it?

You are extending the application class already. You don't need to import it too.

Comment: Debug? Breakpoint..?
Is it a problem, that my class is a .java file?

Comment: I am still waiting on the SDK example downloading, I'll be able to help better once I see it.

Comment: What? It only has 9MB.